# count cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, vector, count

I have an error in my program which says that
'count' cannot be used as a function.

it points to the below line

```
mycount = (int) count (t1q1.begin(), t1q1.end(), 1);
```

i have already included algorithm, using namespace std, but still it shows the error.

This is what I do with my vector t1q1
The below code allows the program to read in the file and extract the certain information and push it back to the vector

MY FUNCTION TO READ FILE AND STORE IT IN VARIABLES

```
void checkForAnswers(char *ptr)
{
    char String[256];
    int count = 0;

    while ( *ptr != ':')
    {
        String[count] = *ptr;
        ptr++;
        count++;
    }

    String[count] = '\0';

     //if topic is 1.
     if (strcmp(String, "1") == 0)
    {
         currentPtr=Travels(':',startPtr);
         int answerone1 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
         currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
         int answertwo2 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
         currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
         int answerthree3 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
         currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
         int answerfour4 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
         currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
         int answerfive5 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);

         t1q1.push_back(answerone1);
         t1q2.push_back(answertwo2);
         t1q3.push_back(answerthree3);
         t1q4.push_back(answerfour4);
         t1q5.push_back(answerfive5);
    }

    if (strcmp(String, "2") == 0)
    {
        currentPtr=Travels(':',startPtr);
        int answerone1 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answertwo2 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answerthree3 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answerfour4 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answerfive5 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);

        t2q1.push_back(answerone1);
        t2q2.push_back(answertwo2);
        t2q3.push_back(answerthree3);
        t2q4.push_back(answerfour4);
        t2q5.push_back(answerfive5);
    }

     if (strcmp(String, "3") == 0)
     {
        currentPtr=Travels(':',startPtr);
        int answerone1 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answertwo2 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answerthree3 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answerfour4 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);
        currentPtr=Travels(':',currentPtr);
        int answerfive5 = (int)atoi(currentPtr);

        t3q1.push_back(answerone1);
        t3q2.push_back(answertwo2);
        t3q3.push_back(answerthree3);
        t3q4.push_back(answerfour4);
        t3q5.push_back(answerfive5);
    }

        currentPtr=0;
}
```

MY MAIN

```
  char Lines1[256];
        int count1 = 0;

        ifstream resultfile("results.txt");
        if (resultfile.is_open())
        {
            do
            {
            resultfile.getline(Lines1, 256);
            startPtr = Lines1;
            checkForAnswers(startPtr);
            count1++;
            }while(resultfile.eof() == false);
        resultfile.close();
        }


    int mycount;
    cout<< "\n";
    cout<< "TABULATION RESULTS\n";
    cout<< "------------------\n";
    cout<< "Topic 1, Question 1\n";
    mycount = (int) count (t1q1.begin(), t1q1.end(), 1);
    cout<< "Option 1: "<< mycount << " time(s)\n";
```

Hope you guys will be able to help me out.
Thanks in advance to those who helped!
:)

Comment: Please post a complete compilable example that exhibits the error.

Comment: There are two different versions of `count`: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/count.html

Comment: @PaulR: There's only one `count` in C++.

Comment: @everyone, updating my thread in abit!

Comment: @Andres have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what made you decide to use `using namespace std;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code `count` refers to the local variable `count`, which has type `int` and thus cannot be used as a function. You should name the variable something else or refer to the function using its qualified name `std::count`.

Also make sure that you `#include <algorithm>` (and have an appropriate `using` declaration if you go the route of renaming the variable and calling the function using its unqualified name).